# Is a flat extension of DVRs always finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, local-rings

Is it true that if $S/\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a flat extension of discrete valuation rings then $S$ is finite over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: Fraction field?

Comment: In my mind, a field is not a DVR. If in yours it is so, let's suppose $S$ is not a field then

Comment: $\Bbb Q_p[[T]]$

Comment: Thakyou for your suggestion. Anyway, my definition for extension of DVRs is that there is an injective local map $\mathbb{Z}_p\to S$, which means that the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ must be contained in the maximal idela of $S$. With this definition, $\mathbb{Q}_p[[T]]$ does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $\mathbb{Z}_p \subset \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}}$ or $\mathbb{Q}[[t]] \subset \mathbb{C}[[t]]$.